# RedirectToAction() breaks umlauts

Tags: c#, utf-8, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

**Note:**
It's *not* `RedirectToAction()` that causes the problem, but rewrite rules in `web.config`

**Original Question:**
There is a strange behaviour when using `RedirectToAction()` which I cannot reproduce locally (debug). At some point my route value gets changed from `äa` to `Ã¤a`, but only on the server (Azure). I added logging to pinpoint the exact spot and ended up here:

```
RedirectToAction("square", new { id = criteria.Trim().ToLower() });
```

Locally this redirects correctly to `/find/square/äa`, but on the server it ends up at `/find/square/Ã¤a`. I logged every step and when my string is passed to `RedirectToAction` it's still intact (even after `Trim()` and `ToLower()`), but broken after redirection. I'm using the default route

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

with controller `find`, action `square` and id `äa` (in this case)

This is pretty surprising to me since .NET is usually very careful and robust when it comes to umlauts and UTF-8. I'm especially lost here, because I'm not able to reproduce the issue locally. I assume it's a server setting, but Azure is pretty sparse at this point. Did anyone experience a similar behaviour before?

Comment: Side note: `/find/square/äa` is invalid uri... Please make sure url you are redirecting to actually correctly encoded (as opposed to what is shown in browser after redirect).

Comment: I'm not sure, this is true, since you can register domain names with umlauts (e.g. öpnvkarte.de). Besides, `RedirectToAction` automatically encodes invalid characters (but did not encode the `ä`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the one part of my code, that I didn't post, the rewrite rules. I only found out after I had a closer look at the redirects in Fiddler. As a matter of fact I found an additional redirect after the one I was intentionally triggering and it was caused by one of my rewrite rules:

```
    <rule name="Lowercase Path" stopProcessing="true" >
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(axd|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|txt|xml|svg|pdf)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{tolower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

In fact it's the following line:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="{tolower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

As soon as I disable this rule, everything works. My other rules which don't use `{ToLower:}` are not producing any problems. I'm not sure, why this doesn't break things locally. While doing my research I found an article describing how Microsoft patched a broken rewrite module which caused similar issues with umlauts. It's speculation, but maybe the rewrite version on my azure instance is unpatched - or it is something completely different.

Unfortunately there are few alternatives to using a rewrite-rule with `{tolower:{URL}}`, so I had to do a rather ugly workaround and check my URL in `Global.asax.cs` like so:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pathAndQuery = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

        if (pathAndQuery == null || Regex.IsMatch(pathAndQuery, @"^.*\.(axd|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|txt|xml|svg|pdf)$"))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(pathAndQuery, ".*[A-Z].*"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(pathAndQuery.ToLower(), false);
            Response.StatusCode = 301;
        }
    }
```

I'm not entirely happy with this approach; it feels smelly, but until I found a better solution this has to suffice.